# Aptitude update 404

Tags: internet, apt, update, aptitude

All I get are the errors below. How can I debug / what might be wrong?

I don't know when this happend, probably just some days ago. Nothing has been changed in the system, that I know of. The only thing I can think of is that my backup disk has run out of space.

```
root@z:~# aptitude update
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic Release.gpg
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates Release.gpg
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic Release
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net karmic Release.gpg
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net karmic/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates Release
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security Release.gpg
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/restricted Translation-en_US
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/universe Translation-en_US
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net karmic Release
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/multiverse Translation-en_US
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security Release
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/restricted Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net karmic/main Packages
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main Sources
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/restricted Sources
Ign http://apt.bijk.com hardy Release.gpg
Ign http://apt.bijk.com hardy/main Translation-en_US
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/universe Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/main Packages
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/universe Sources
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/multiverse Packages
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/multiverse Sources
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/main Packages
Ign http://apt.bijk.com hardy Release
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/restricted Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/restricted Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/main Sources
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/main Sources
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/restricted Sources
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/universe Packages
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/restricted Sources
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/universe Sources
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/universe Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/multiverse Packages
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/universe Sources
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/multiverse Sources
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/main Packages
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/multiverse Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/restricted Packages
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/multiverse Sources
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/main Sources
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/restricted Sources
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/universe Packages
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/restricted Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/universe Sources
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main Sources
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/multiverse Packages
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/multiverse Sources
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/restricted Sources
Err http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/main Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/universe Packages
Err http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/restricted Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/universe Sources
Err http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/universe Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/multiverse Packages
Err http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/multiverse Sources
Err http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/multiverse Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/main Packages
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/restricted Packages
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net karmic/main Packages
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/main Sources
Ign http://apt.bijk.com hardy/main Packages
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/restricted Sources
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/universe Packages
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/universe Sources
Err http://ppa.launchpad.net karmic/main Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/multiverse Packages
Ign http://apt.bijk.com hardy/main Packages
Ign http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/multiverse Sources
Err http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/restricted Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://apt.bijk.com hardy/main Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/universe Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://security.ubuntu.com karmic-security/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/multiverse Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/main Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/restricted Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/restricted Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/universe Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/universe Sources
  404  Not Found
Err http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/multiverse Packages
  404  Not Found
Err http://se.archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/multiverse Sources
  404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done
```

In `/var/log/syslog` there are a lot of

```
Nov 17 18:42:52 z named[1233]: network unreachable resolving 'ns-932.amazon.com/A/IN': 2001:500:94:1::31#53
```

and similar.

Also, `ddclient` has broken down.

```
Nov 17 18:41:33 z ddclient[1269]: WARNING:  file /var/cache/ddclient/ddclient.cache, line 3: Invalid Value for keyword 'ip' = ''
Nov 17 18:41:33 z ddclient[1269]: WARNING:  file /var/cache/ddclient/ddclient.cache, line 4: Invalid Value for keyword 'ip' = ''
```

I think that is related.

Appreciate all help here!

---

**Update:**

```
$ dig @130.244.196.98 ns-932.amazon.com

; <<>> DiG 9.6.1-P2 <<>> @130.244.196.98 ns-932.amazon.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 8791
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 2
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;ns-932.amazon.com.             IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
ns-932.amazon.com.      1       IN      A       130.244.196.98

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
.                       1       IN      NS      localhost.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
localhost.              604800  IN      A       127.0.0.1
localhost.              604800  IN      AAAA    ::1

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 130.244.196.98#53(130.244.196.98)
;; WHEN: Wed Nov 17 22:19:31 2010
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 117
```

**Update 2:**

```
# cat /etc/ddclient.conf
# Configuration file for ddclient generated by debconf
#
# /etc/ddclient.conf

use=if, if=eth0


######################################################################
##
## $Id: ddclient.conf 1 2008-03-20 10:20:00 Loopia $
##
## LoopiaDNS (www.loopia.se/loopiadns/)
## (supports variables: wildcard,mx,backupmx)
##
######################################################################
daemon=300                              # check every 300 seconds
syslog=yes                              # log update msgs to syslog
mail=root                               # mail all msgs to root
mail-failure=root                       # mail failed update msgs to root
pid=/var/run/ddclient.pid               # record PID in file.
ssl=yes                                 # use ssl-support.  Works with
                                        # ssl-library
#
## Default settings for LoopiaDNS
protocol=dyndns2                                # default protocol
custom=yes                                      # default system
server=dns.loopia.se/XDynDNSServer/XDynDNS.php  # default server
#
## To obtain an IP address from Web status page
#use=web, web=dns.loopia.se/checkip/checkip.php, web-skip='Current IP Address:'
#
## Default logon information
login=mydomain1.com                               # default login
password='mypassword'                               # default password
#
## Optional settings
#mx=mail.mindoman.se                            # default MX
#backupmx=no                                    # host is primary MX?
#wildcard=no                                    # add wildcard CNAME?
#
## What hosts to update; mindoman.se,www.mindoman.se
my-server.mydomain1.com, mydomain2.com
```

Comment: What happens when you run `curl -v http://se.archive.ubuntu.com`?

Comment: Can't install curl when apt can't access the servers :( But the server acts as a router/NAT among other things, and all computers connected  to it can access se.archive.ubuntu.com fine

Comment: Try: `dig @130.244.196.98 ns-932.amazon.com` to see if the NS is responding to queries correctly. (It could be pingable but still broken)

Also, what does the `hosts:` line of `/etc/nsswitch.conf` say?

Comment: Ah, my apologies.  I thought `curl` was installed by default on an Ubuntu install.  It may not be the reason for your issues, but it appears very clearly that your `ddclient` install is not properly configured--which might explain why `dig` works but accessing the URL via other methods does not.  How about pasting your `/etc/ddclient.conf` (or wherever you have it stored)?

Comment: Added `ddclient.conf`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem finally solved!

I stumbled upon a message from my ISP with an upgrade schedule for my network, and it said I would need to sign in.

Correct me if I'm wrong, but all computers in my local network worked since they used bind on the server to resolve hostnames. I guess the server was not.

A couple of minutes after I removed the ddclient cache file my domain names were alive again.

The upside is that I'm now on 100 Mbit :-)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your resolver configuration is out of date

Are the nameservers in `/etc/resolv.conf` reachable?
Does `host se.archive.ubuntu.com` return ip-addresses?
I can `ping se.archive.ubuntu.com` - can you?

Comment: `host` and `ping` works, and I can ping the nameserver `nameserver 130.244.196.98` from `resolv.conf`.